# How to insert data into lookup relationship object and show all child object data into parent object related to that parent Id

Tags: apex, api, lookup

I am trying to write an api to insert data into the lookup relationship objects and retrieve all child data into parent object for that parent id. (suppose i am inserting 3 child object records for one parent object it should display all 3 records in parent) I have write a code but it is showing only one record.

## apex Code

```
global static string lead(String firstName,String lastName, String 
   company, String status,String Projeted_project_status, Contact[] Contact, String name)
   {
    Lead lead=new Lead();
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  lead.FirstName=firstName;
  lead.LastName=lastName;
  lead.Company=company;
  lead.Status=status;
  lead.Projected_Project_Start__c=Projeted_project_status;
  Insert lead;

Contact[] cont=new List<Contact>();
   for(Contact contct: cont){
       
       contct.LastName=name;
       contct.LeadRelated__c=lead.Id;  
       Insert contct;        
   }
}
```

Comment: First i would suggest you to figure out your exact requirements. For instance if you are going to insert multiple child records for parent your method signature should be like this which provide a list. I don't think you would want same name for all the child records. Currently if you see you are only inserting one child record that's why it is only showing 1 child record.

Comment: yes i want to insert multiple records. but i dont have any idea how to do it.